# Como inserir um valor utilizando o event keydown ou keypress com Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço para para inserir uma palavra no `value` de um `input` utilizando **keydown** ou **keypress** ao invés de setar o valor através de um método.

Como por exemplo, não quero utilizar método como: `$("#coupon").value = "teste"`. Quero simular que a tecla "a" foi digitada dentro do input.

Tentei o seguinte código javascript no meu HTML para inserir o texto "a" dentro do `value` do `input`, simulando a ação do teclado, mas não funcionou:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#coupon');
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'a'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="coupon" type="text" required="required" />
```

Comment: Veja [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Sugiro [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/522867/edit) sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes, tentativas e etc, para que atenda os critérios de um [mre]. Sua pergunta não está clara, especifique e exemplifique com mais detalhes!

Comment: @gleisin-dev expliquei melhor o que quero e meu código foi com base na documentação, postei a ajuda aqui porque o código não funcionou e queria ver se alguém com mais experiência pudesse ajudar a fazer funcionar.

Comment: mas como assim simular? digitar fora e aplicar o valor dentro do input? ou digitar dentro do input porém não usar a propriedade `val()` ou `value()`

Comment: Isso, não quero setar o valor utilizando métodos como `val()` ou `value()`, preciso simular que isso foi digitado pelo teclado, como se tivesse ditado a letra "a" pelo teclado.

Comment: você pode utilizar o `jQuery(this).attr('value', KeyboardEvent.key);`